# How to call javascript function with parameter in jquery event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck. Searched and tried for hours.

EDIT:
I still can't make it work. Okay, I'll just put the source code to make it clear what I want to accomplish.

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var date_fmt="yyyy-mm-dd";
    var time_fmt="HH:MM";
    var date_field="#id_start_0, #id_end_0"; //id refering to html input type='text'
    var time_field="#id_start_1, #id_end_1"; //id refereing to html input type='text'


    function clearFmt(fmt_type)
    { 
        if($(this).val() == fmt_type) {
            $(this).val("");

        }
    }

    function putFmt(fmt_type)
    {
        if($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val(fmt_type);
        }
    }


$(document).ready(function() {

    $(date_field).attr("title",date_fmt);
    $(time_field).attr("title",time_fmt);

    $(date_field).click(function() {
        clearFmt(date_fmt);
    });   

    $(date_field).blur(function(){
        putFmt(date_fmt);
    });

    $(time_field).click(function(){
        clearFmt(time_fmt);
    });   

    $(time_field).blur(function(){
        putFmt(time_fmt);
    });

});
</script>
```

Help ?

Comment: You want myFunc to be evaluated at click time versus at instantiation, correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the jquery [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method:

```
function myfunc(param) {
    alert(param.data.key);
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#foo").bind('click', { key: 'value' }, myfunc);
});
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Bhpb/).

=== UPDATE ===

since jquery 1.4.3 you also can use:

```
function myfunc(param) {
    alert(param.data.key);
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#foo").click({ key: 'value' }, myfunc);
});
```

Also see my second [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Bhpb/1/).

=== UPDATE 2 ===

Each function has his own `this`. After calling `clearFmt` in this function `this` is no longer the clicked element. I have two similar solutions:

In your functions add a parameter called e.g. `element` and replace `$(this)` with `element`.

```
function clearFmt(element, fmt_type) {
    if (element.val() == fmt_type) {
        element.val("");
    }
}
```

Calling the function you have to add the parameter `$(this)`.

```
$(date_field).click(function() {
    clearFmt($(this), date_fmt);
});
```

Also see my [third jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qa7yP/).

-=-

An alternative:

```
function clearFmt(o) {
    if ($(o.currentTarget).val() == o.data.fmt_type) {
        $(o.currentTarget).val("");
    }
}
$(date_field).click({fmt_type: date_fmt}, clearFmt);
```

Also see my [fourth jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qa7yP/1/).

Comment: Thanks alot! I use your 3rd jsfiddle solution.

Answer (score 4):

The following should work as seen in this [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tqxdV/):

```
function myfunc(bar) {
    alert(bar);
}

$(function() {
    $("#foo").click( function() {
        myfunc("value");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
anyFunctionName = (function()
{
    function yourFunctionName1()
    {
        //your code here 
    }

    function yourFunctionName2(parameter1, param2)
    {
        //your code here 
    }

    return
    {
        yourFunctionName1:yourFunctionName1,
        yourFunctionName2:yourFunctionName2
    }
})();

$document.ready(function()
{
    anyFunctionName.yourFunctionName1();
    anyFunctionName.yourFunctionName2();
});
```

Note: if you don't use 'anyFuctionName' to declare any function then no need return method. just write your function simply like, yourFunctionName1().

in $document.ready section parameter is not issue. you just put your function name here. if you  use 'anyFuctionName' function then you have to follow above format.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunc(e) {
  alert(e.data.bar); //this is set to "value"
}

$("#foo").click({bar: "value"}, myfunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

People are making this complicated, simply call directly as you would in Javascript

myfunc("value");