# Calling a Separate Function on Double Click JQuery

Tags: jquery, function, double-click

I am using the JQuery Double Click function which appends a string of text on a div when the double click happens on that div. What I want to do is make the text append be a part of a separate function which gets called when the double click happens.

My current code is:

```
$(".class").dblclick(function() {

   $(".class").append(text);

});
```

What I want to do is have a separate function instead of `$(".class").append(text);` and then define this function using this line somewhere else in the code. How could I replace this line `$(".class").append(text);` with a function and then define it somewhere else?

Hope this makes sense, thank you!

Comment: You can write a function in javascript `function myFunction(){
   $(".class").append(text);
}`. And call on dbl click  `$(".class").dblclick(function() {
  myFunction();
 });`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call javascript function with parameter in jquery event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510654/how-to-call-javascript-function-with-parameter-in-jquery-event-handler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a new function and call the  `$(".class").append(text);` inside of it, then call this function on the Double Click function. Something like this:

```
$(".class").dblclick(function() {
    appendText();
});

function appendText(){
    $(".class").append(text);
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

$(this) function will be help you for using another method.

```
$('.class').dblclick(function () {
    appendText($(this).text());
})

function appendText(text) {
    console.log(text.trim());
}
```